# Definition of conical symplectic form

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

[image]

**Question:** I am having trouble understanding where the definition of $\bar{\omega}$ comes from. I understand that it should be a $2$-form on $cL_s$ undergoing pullback. With this said, why is the argument $\bar{\omega}([z,t])$ instead of just $\bar{\omega}(z,t)$? How does the rest of $(4.1)$ come into play?

**Reference:** The link to these notes is [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1006.5707.pdf).

**Update:** After some more careful reading, I found that  $\bar{\omega}([z,t])$ is the $(0,2)$-tensor at the point $[z,t] \in cL_s(\epsilon_s)$, where $[z,t]$ is the image of $(z,t)$ under the natural projection $\pi: L \times [0, \infty)  \to cL$. I still need help understanding the right hand side of $(4.1)$.